# how to put horizontal scroll with grow shrink animation on icons in android?

Tags: android, animation, horizontal-scrolling

I need to design an android app where in i have to display the home page as the below image. there will be 4-5 icons to which i need to give a horizontal scroll animation at an angle and the icon at the center will enlarge and have an on click listener to proceed to the respective activity of the particular icon clicked. I am very much new to android. I do not have any idea how to do these scroll animations. How do i start?? If anybody can please guide me through this??? 
Please help!!

Thanks in advance!!

[image: Sample design]

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is some what `3D Carousel` type style.

Check out [Android 3D Carousel](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

This may help you to get a start up. Making some changes in this project may help you achieve your goal.

Comment: How do i make this 3D animation into a 2D animation as per my requirement??? Any idea?